# django-bootstrap4 my form always has is-valid tags, how to stop this?

Tags: django, bootstrap-4, django-forms

Summary: I am upgrading a django-project from bootstrap3 to bootstrap4, so I am using django-bootstrap4 now.
The is-valid tags on form elements are, after upgrade to bootstrap4, rendering a big green tick and making the form fields wider.

How do I stop is-valid tags being added? This is even before the form has been submitted.

There is no validation logic.

more:

I have a filter form generated on some of my pages

```
{% if filter %}
    <form action="" method="get" class="form form-inline">
        {% bootstrap_form filter.form layout='inline' %}
        {% bootstrap_button 'filter' %}
    </form>
{% endif %}
```

The form fields are generating markup like:

```
       <div class="form-group is-valid">
    <label class="sr-only" for="id_order_number__icontains">Order number contains</label>

<input type="text" name="order_number__icontains" class="form-control is-valid" placeholder="Order number contains" title="order_number__icontains" id="id_order_number__icontains">
    </div>
```

The `<input>` element has been assigned `class is-valid`. This happens to all elements.
Previously this happened too, but there was no visual effect. Bootstrap4 is making the field wider and displaying a big green tick. I don't think the fields should be marked is-invalid before submission, this doesn't make much sense to me. I don't have validation scripts, and if I disable javascript on the page, I get the same result anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You appear to be using a form to filter a queryset. Naturally such forms would be bound irrespective of whether the form is submitted since they are always passed the GET parameters, and hence would be valid even when rendered first when not submitted.

If you don't want the `is_valid` class to be added you can pass the class that should be rendered instead as the keyword argument `bound_css_class` to the `bootstrap_form` template tag:

```
{% bootstrap_form filter.form layout='inline' bound_css_class='' %}
```

Comment: thanks. This explains the is_valid class. I filed a ticket to the project and a project member said he is working on this for the pending bootstrap5 version, and potentially backporting it. I used settngs.py BOOTSTRAP4 as {'success_css_class':None} but your approach is better, I will try it soon. Had no idea you could pass keywords like that.

Comment: @TimRichardson for some reason it is not present in the documentation for the template tags all the kwargs that can be passed (which would be many) but looking at the code we can see that the template tag passes all of its kwargs to the renderer class, which is why we can pass `bound_css_class` here. **Edit**: I see they mention "_See bootstrap\_field\_ for other arguments_" instead where these arguments are mentioned, so very easy to overlook when reading the documentation.